# logistic regression does not show good results in confusion matrix

Tags: logistic, scikit-learn

I am using the following dataset, original version, obtained from:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/

I want to apply logistic regression to classify the samples on that dataset, my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = np.genfromtxt("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data",delimiter=",")
X = data[:,1:-1]
X[X == '?'] = '-999999'
X = X.astype(int)
y = data[:, -1].astype(int)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2)
lg=linear_model.LogisticRegression(n_jobs = 10)
lg.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = lg.predict(X_test)
cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions)
print(cm)
score = lg.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (score.mean(), score.std() * 2))
```

The attributes are the following:

```
 #  Attribute                     Domain
   -- -----------------------------------------
   1. Sample code number            id number
   2. Clump Thickness               1 - 10
   3. Uniformity of Cell Size       1 - 10
   4. Uniformity of Cell Shape      1 - 10
   5. Marginal Adhesion             1 - 10
   6. Single Epithelial Cell Size   1 - 10
   7. Bare Nuclei                   1 - 10
   8. Bland Chromatin               1 - 10
   9. Normal Nucleoli               1 - 10
  10. Mitoses                       1 - 10
  11. Class:                        (2 for benign, 4 for malignant)
```

I have deleted the first column because it is only the ID, and replaced the ? characters with a big number, so that it could be classified as an outlier. The problem I got is when I compare my results to the ones obtained in this page:

https://anujdutt9.github.io/ML_LogRSklearn.html

Because I am obtaining an accuracy of:

```
Accuracy: 0.34
```

and on the link mentioned before the accuracy was approximately 95%.

The results of my confusion matrix are also poor, for example, I obtain:

```
[[ 1 92]
 [ 0 47]]
```

From my data I can see that is not necessary to apply normalization and in a lot of examples I see that one can use logistic regression.

What is wrong with my model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of it, I can see 4 points to improve here:

1) Replacing the ? with -9999 would never be a good idea. Either drop those observations or find a more clever way to fill them up (e.g, use the mean/median/ or even predict them by regressing on other predictors).

2) Even though the variables seem to be in the same order of magnitude, I'd still normalize the data.

3) Check for whether some variables are highly correlated. This could also screw up your results.

4) And of course, check that you are not overfitting your training set. But you don't have a lot of variables, so that should be fine.

Edit:

you can use this and replace the value -9999 with -2147483648 and see what you get.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

data = pd.read_csv("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt",delimiter=",")


# list_mask = []
# for index in range(data.shape[0]):
#     if sum(data.iloc[index] == '?') != 0:
#         list_mask.append(False)
#     else:
#         list_mask.append(True)

# data = data[list_mask]

data.replace(to_replace='?', value=-2147483648, inplace=True)

X, y = data.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]], data.iloc[:,[10]]
print(X.shape, y.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2)
lg= LogisticRegression(n_jobs = 1)
lg.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = lg.predict(X_test)

score = lg.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (score.mean(), score.std() * 2))
```

Comment: I saw that in the programming example provided on the link that I mentioned it works the model, but I cannot get what is wrong with mine

Comment: Actually i just noticed that the variables are 1-10, so no need to do point 2). Can you try by removing the -9999 and just removing these rows instead. It is usually not advised to replace by arbitrary large values like that as it will affect your results (unless you are using trees).

Comment: Ah right, so that's because what you do is not correct. He replaces the value using a panda dataframe, while you are using a numpy array. I replicated what you did and it turns out that you are replacing the '?' with -2147483648 rather than with -9999. And i also got 0.36 accuracy with those values. With -9999, I got 0.95. This is why it does not make sense to replace a NaN with an arbitrary value (even more so arbitrary large value)